# How can I prevent a form from saving in Dynamics 365

Tags: javascript, forms, event-handling, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I want to prevent a form from saving if the entered "dni" value is already registered by another "person", I tried to keep the form from saving in its onSave event, and then if my condition matched, I'd make the form save then. So I made the following code:

```
function saveDni(executionContext) {
  try {
    const formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
    const currentDni = formContext.getAttribute("cr6ff_dni").getValue();
    
    executionContext.getEventArgs().preventDefault();

    var fetchXml = [
      "<fetch top='1'>",
      "  <entity name= 'cr6ff_person'>",
      "    <filter>",
      "      <condition attribute='cr6ff_dni' operator='eq' value='", currentDni, "'/>",
      "    </filter>",
      "  </entity>",
      "</fetch>",
    ].join("");

    fetchXml = "?fetchXml=" + encodeURIComponent(fetchXml);

    Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords("cr6ff_person", fetchXml).then(
      (result) => {
        if (result.entities.length == 0) {
          formContext.data.entity.save();
        }
     }
   ) 
}
catch(error) {
  console.log("An error has occurred while validating the user's data.");
}
```

The thing is, when the save() method triggers, it also triggers this function back again, so I'm stuck in a loop. Any ideas as to how I could work this out?

Comment: instead of javascript you can make that field to be an alternate key, in that way you force to be unique https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/define-alternate-keys-entity

Comment: That's clever! I'll keep that in mind for future solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me recommend you the best practices.

1. Avoid Asynchronous calls like `Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords` in form save for better User experience. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/events/form-onsave)
2. `formContext.data.entity.save()` is deprecated, use `formContext.data.save()` instead. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/formcontext-data-entity/save)
3. Better to move the business logic validation to server side plugin or Power automate flow

Comment: Will follow your advice, thank you for the insight provided!

Comment: Avoid Asynchronous calls like Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords ? Huh?
Why would you give such strange advice? There's nothing wrong with using that.

Comment: @ironarm pls justify your point.. I accept your challenge professionally :)

Comment: You know what, my bad. Why you shouldn't skim read. I read your comment as, avoid async calls like Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords entirely.  But, you meant specifically for the "save" event, correct? I will remove my down vote.

Comment: @ironarm understood, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this line to prevent to save a form in d365.

```
executionContext.getEventArgs().preventDefault();
```